# Receive error "Application has stopped working" when opening via Process.Start()

Tags: c#, .net

I have a 3rd party software package. Its folder contains the `.exe` file to run and some other files required to run the application. When I open the application manually, it works fine, but when I try to open the same application through `Process.Start()`, I get the error "application has stopped working".

The application needs the .NET 4.0 framework in order to execute, so I had to install it. The C# code I'm attempting to run it with is on .NET 3.5 and was created using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Show the code that you use to create your process.

Comment: Try checking the windows event log and see whether it gives error logging

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong current directory. We can't tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
    var path = @"C:\Temp\test.exe";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);

    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
    info.WorkingDirectory = fi.DirectoryName;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = info;

    process.Start();
```

If this does not work, try

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(fi.DirectoryName);
```

directly before the `process.Start();`

Do not forget to reset the Current directory afterwards!
Save the CurrentDirectory before with

```
var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: this thing worked great thanks bud . Is there any way how i can communicate with the third party software in the background for sending and receiving calculated data etc?